# postfix multiple recipients for the one address

Tags: centos, email, postfix, email-server

I'm running postfix on centos and in my /etc/postfix/address I have

```
email@domain.com username
```

which works and now I want two people to be on that list now. I've tried

```
email@domain.com username, username2
```

or

```
email@domain.com username
email@domain.com username2
```

but neither get to username 2. How do I do this using address or should I do it another way?

Comment: What does your maillog say?

Comment: Do you want to forward the mail to their mailbox or do you want to have it as sort of shared mailbox?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

Comment: Could you give a bit more info? All the examples I see just show a 1 to 1 mapping and I can't find any examples of multiple ones.

Comment: @Rudiger: you have to use your first method:
user1@virtual-alias.domain address1,address2
as mentioned in the virtual manpage. You also have to include your /etc/postfix/address file within the parameter virtual_alias_maps. And you have to create the corresponding hashfile with the command postmap /etc/postfix/address". If you have still problems after these steps then it would help to see the output of "postconf -n" and maybe your logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Quick Setup that hopefully will alleviate the pain I went through to find a concise answer to this:

/etc/postfix/virtual - Postfix virtual alias table

Quick set up to allow replacement of one address with multiple addresses:

1. If not existing, add

   virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

   to bottom of /etc/postfix/main.cf
2. Restart postfix - systemctl restart postfix
3. Add entry for email To: address to replace in /etc/postfix/virtual, example:

   user-z@localhost.localdomain user-x@domain1.com,user-y@domain2.com
4. Run 'postmap /etc/postfix/virtual' to insert into database
5. Run 'postmap -q user-z@localhost.localdomain /etc/postfix/virtual' to check binding, example:

   user-x@domain1.com,user-y@domain2.com
6. Run 'postmap -d user-z@localhost.localdomain /etc/postfix/virtual' to delete binding

Note on source address (the one replaced) - its domain must be DNS resolvable to be mailable. 'user@localhost.localdomain' will resolve at least to the local server and can be used to test. Beyond testing, to sucessfully mail the server must have an active DNS A record and that must be included by using any user, existing or not, '@', and the fully qualified domain name of the server.

For example, if server01 is the local server, this is the entry in /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
user-a@server01.subdomain.domain.net user-a@subdomain.domain.net,user-b@domain02.net
```

Here a non-user account (user-a@server01.subdomain.domain.net), which is not an actual user on server01.subdomain.domain.net, nor has a valid email address, however can be used locally on server01 as well as by any remotes relaying through it to get rewritten to go to user-a@subdomain.domain.net and user-b@domain02.net.